# Elegant way to get non empty list or `[[]]` (default value) in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, default-value

Is it possible to simplify the definition of this function, which returns `[[]]` if `l` is empty and `l` otherwise?

```
f :: Eq t => [[t]] -> [[t]]
f l = if l == [] then [[]] else l
```

for ex. in python I can do this:

```
f = lambda l: l or [[]]
```

I thought about applicative:

```
f l = l <|> [[]]
```

but it appends `[]` in case of the non-empty `l`

Is there any way to do this more elegantly in Haskell?

Comment: One minor improvement you can make is to replace `l == []` with `null l`. More significantly, I suppose you could do `f = bool <$> id <*> (const [[]]) <*> null`, but it’s debatable whether that’s more ‘elegant’ or just more obfuscated. The only reason the Python code works is that the null list gets automatically converted to ‘falsy’ and thus can be used with logical operators; Haskell isn’t that weakly typed, so finding such an elegant solution would be a bit trickier in Haskell.

Comment: Hmm, just thought of another possible solution, exploiting [`Data.List.NonEmpty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html): `toList . fromMaybe (pure []) . nonEmpty`. But again, it’s more obfuscatory than elegant.

Answer (score 3):

If you need `Eq` only to check whether a list is empty, you are doing it wrong.

```
f :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
f [] = [[]]
f x  = x
```

Or, if you prefer if-then-else:

```
f :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
f x = if null x then [[]] else x
```

Or perhaps more generally:

```
class Fallible a where
   failed ∷ a -> Bool

instance Fallible [a] where
   failed = null

orelse ∷ Fallible a => a -> a -> a  
orelse x y = if failed x then y else x

f :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
f x = x `orelse` [[]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly some improvements one could make, although I wouldn't call any of them simplifications. First, we can get rid of the `Eq` constraint, by using pattern matching instead:

```
f :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
f [] = [[]]
f x = x
```

Or we could get rid of it in another way, by using `foldr`:

```
f :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
f x = foldr (const (const x)) [[]] x
```

Now we don't actually need the input to be a list anymore. It could be anything Foldable, except that it has to be the same as the output type. But the only reason we need the output to be a list is so we can build a singleton out of it. So we don't really need to specialize to list after all - anything Applicative will do:

```
f :: (Foldable f, Applicative f) => f [a] -> f [a]
f x = foldr (const (const x)) (pure []) x
```

Finally we could try to generalize over the last `[]`, to make this function applicable in the most places possible. Some obvious choices for `[]` are Monoid or Alternative - either of these have a concept of emptiness. I'd probably choose Monoid for being the simplest, yielding:

```
f :: (Foldable f, Applicative f, Monoid a) => f a -> f a
f x = foldr (const (const x)) (pure mempty) x
```

What does all this abstraction buy us? We can now do a similar operation with different data types. Suppose, for example, we arbitrarily choose `f ~ Maybe` and `a ~ Ordering`. Then our function acts like this (inlining definitions from the relevant typeclass instances):

```
f :: Maybe Ordering -> Maybe Ordering
f (Just result) = Just result
f Nothing = Just EQ
```

Kinda a weird function (it would be more natural to unwrap the Maybe than to put it in `Just`), but I'd argue no weirder than your original function (why is `[[]]` any better than `[]` anyway?).

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `ZipList` for this:

```hs
> ZipList [[1, 2, 3]] <|> ZipList [[]]
ZipList {getZipList = [[1, 2, 3]]}

> ZipList [[1, 2], [3]] <|> ZipList [[]]
ZipList {getZipList = [[1, 2], [3]]}

> ZipList [[]] <|> ZipList [[]]
ZipList {getZipList = [[]]}

> ZipList [] <|> ZipList [[]]
ZipList {getZipList = [[]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo :: [[t]] -> [[t]]
foo xs  =  head  $  (xs <$ xs)  <|>  [ [[]] ]
      -- take one of
      --         either `xs`    OR    the default
```

Notice the type though. It will only work for `[[t]]` lists, because that's the type of `[[]]`.

It might feel a bit obfuscated, unless you've become comfortable with the `xs <$ xs` trick (which is the same as `[xs | _ <- xs]`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by elegant, but if you want to write it in a style that more closely resembles the Python, you can write:

```hs
import Data.Function ((&))
import Data.Bool (bool)

f :: [[t]] -> [[t]]
f l = null l & l `bool` [[]]
```

The `bool` function takes as arguments first the else/`False` case and then the then/`True` case and finally the boolean that it's checking.  Here, we use infix notation to provide it with its first two arguments.  In other words, `` l `bool` [[]] `` has the type `Bool -> [[t]]`.  Finally, the operator `&` is a flipped version of `$`—that is, it takes the argument first and then the function.  Here, we provide `null l` as the argument, and the function is `` l `bool` [[]] ``.

---

Unfortunately the `:` symbol is reserved in Haskell.  On the other hand, the `?` symbol isn't.  So, if you're okay with `&`, we can at least redefine `bool` and achieve:

```hs
(?) = bool

f :: [[t]] -> [[t]]
f l = null l & l ? [[]]
```

It's certainly concise, and it's similar to short-hand if-statements from other languages.